# Pi in C language

Tags: c, floating-point, pi

So i was trying to get the value of pi in c (IDE = DEV C++) so i am using long double in this and the result it is giving me is a complete set of zeros
here is the program

```
int main() 
{
    long double rootOf3;

    rootOf3 = (22.0/7.0);

    printf("%lf", rootOf3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

after that i found out that the value of pi is not precise in c and is already declared in math.h and when  i tried to get the value with this code

```
int main() 
{

    printf("%f", M_PI);
    printf("%e", M_PI);
    printf("%lf", M_PI);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

i get these value

```
3.1415933.141593e+0003.141593Press any key to continue . . .
```

so my questions

1) what is the mistake in the first program and can i get the values of pi with the above code using long double
  2)is it true that in c the value of pi is not accurate?an why am i not getting the entire pi value assigned in math.h

thanks

Comment: Read much more about [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).  Code `printf("%e\n", M_PI);` etc... Read about variadic argument passing and promotion of `float` argument to `double`

Comment: By its nature Pi is never calculated accurate.

Comment: Read also http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: [π is not 22/7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_π) — [π is 4](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/is-value-of-pi-4).

Comment: Basile thanks brother awsome links

Comment: what pi is 4? when from?

Comment: If you are using the 22/7 approximation there is no point using more than float. 22/7 differs from PI in the third digit after the decimal point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For printing a `long double`, use `"%Lf"`. Use of `"%lf"` for `long double` causes undefined behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
   long double pi = 22.0/7.0;
   printf("%Lf\n", pi);
   printf("%lf\n", pi);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.142857
0.000000
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

It's difficult to see the how accurately a number is represented using `float`, `double`, and `long double` using the default settings in `printf`. By using a format that prints more digits after the decimal point,  the differences will be clearer.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test1()
{
   float pi = 22.0f/7.0;
   printf("=== float ================\n");
   printf("%.25lf\n", pi);
   printf("%lf\n", pi);
}

void test2()
{
   double pi = 22.0/7.0;
   printf("=== double ===============\n");
   printf("%.25lf\n", pi);
   printf("%lf\n", pi);
}

void test3()
{
   long double pi = 22.0L/7.0;
   printf("=== long double ==========\n");
   printf("%.25Lf\n", pi);
   printf("%Lf\n", pi);
}

int main(void)
{
   test1();
   test2();
   test3();
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
=== float ================
3.1428570747375488281250000
3.142857
=== double ===============
3.1428571428571427937015414
3.142857
=== long double ==========
3.1428571428571428572357888
3.142857
```

Comment: You are still missing a key piece: The computation `22.0/7.0` is done with `double` precision only.

Comment: if i use a long double should i not get more accuracy or more number of floating point of numbers? What is its use if it gives me the same value as a normal float

Comment: @psraganvesh The division `22.0/7.0` is done with `double` precision as both `22.0` and `7.0` have type `double`. Use `22.0l/7.0l` to make a division with `long double` precision.

Comment: @psraganvesh, how are you judging that? From the output of `printf`?

Comment: yes and i am new to programming and stackoverflow sorry if that is a silly mistake am i wrong@RSahu

Comment: @FUZxxl so if i want a long double precision i have to put 1 at the end or what is the symbol?

Comment: @psraganvesh You need to suffix floating point literals with `l` or `L` (an ell, not a one) to make them have double precision.

Comment: @RShau thanks now that I understand it clearly but why is this difference occurring is it a compiler independent thing or rounding numbers (from what I heard)  or is it that c does not handle these kinds of things properly?  And does every language have the same problem sorry if too many questions.  I'm new to programing and I am generally very curious.  Thanks again

Comment: @psraganvesh, floating point numbers cannot be represented precisely by the computer. The accuracy with which a floating point number can be represented by a computer depends on the number of bits used to represent it. You can read more about it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point.